# Ruby - while loop looping when I believe it shouldn't

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I have some problem with this code below. It's pretty simple, but the most awkward thing for me is that it actually works.

Here we have a program that shuffles items in previously input array, and it's printing it to the screen. That's it.

Now , why is it so weird for me?
All comes down to `count` variable , `y` variable and `while loop`.
I was explaining this code to myself step by step and still I don't know how it is possible for this program to analyse last item in the array, and all due to

```
while y <= count
  x = rand(count+1)

  if array[x] != 'used'
    randomized.push array[x]
    array [x] = 'used'
    y = y + 1

  end
```

I just don't get it. If I create an array with three items
`array = ["a","b","c"]` Then variable `count` is equal to `1`. And `y` variable is equal to `0` in the beginning and at the very end of the loop we increase `y` by `1`. This `while loop` should be repeating only two times like in condition `while y <= count` , why?

Because firstly our `y` is `0` , and it's less than count which is `1`. So here we have our first 
walk through our loop.
Now it's time for second walk through loop, `y = 1`, `count = 1` , they are equal, here we go.
And now it's doing third walkthrough. while `y = 2` and `count = 1`.

Can anybody explain me how is it possible?

```
# starting condition
list = [ ]

# as the question
puts 'Enter a list of words, press \'enter\' to quit and they will be returned   
randomly shuffled.'
word = 'one'

# get the words in the first list
while word != ''
  word = gets.chomp
  list.push word
end

# define shuffle method
def shuffle array

  # starting conditions of local variables
  randomized = [ ]
  count = -2
  x = 0
  y = 0


  array.each do |word|
    count = count + 1
  end

  while y <= count    
    x = rand(count+1)    
    if array[x] != 'used'
      randomized.push array[x]
      array [x] = 'used'
      y = y + 1
    end
  end

  puts randomized

end

shuffle list
```

Comment: Why should count change? it doesn't look like it changes at all within this while loop (assuming this is a top level set of methods, not a monkey patch on array)

Comment: *"press 'enter' to quit"* - the last item in `list` is always an empty string, maybe that's causing the confusion?

Comment: Yes, I was blind to the fact that when you leave blank space and press enter you actually add it to the array. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the count is 1 with `array = ["a","b","c"]`.

However, when you do:

```
while word != ''
  word = gets.chomp
  list.push word
end
```

You actually get an `array = ["a","b","c",""]`. Therefore, the count is actually 2.

This does not cause problems later because, the line `x = rand(count+1)` ensures that the last element never gets selected.